# Error: style attribute '@android:attr/windowExitAnimation' not found

Tags: android, android-instant-apps, gradle-3.0

I recently upgraded to the gradle-3.0.0-alpha8 after which some styles are not resolved at compile time.
Develop envirment:

- IDE:  Android studio 3.0 Bate3
- Gradle build tools : 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta3'
- Gradle :gradle-4.1-all.zip

Error info:

> ```
>     Error:(94, 5) style attribute '@android:attr/windowExitAnimation' not found
>     Error:(94, 5) style attribute '@android:attr/windowEnterAnimation' not found
> ```

Setting android.enableAapt2=false in gradle.properties file can  solve this isuue.

But, Instant App need android.enableAapt2=true. What would i do?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html

Comment: Can you try it with Android Studio Beta 2? Because Beta 3 version was removed https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/08/android-studio-30-beta-3-is-now.html  (with android.enableAapt2)

Comment: I found a similar issue reported in public tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65036100

Answer (score 71):

All the problem was solved already.

Cause of the problem：

There are two modules, A_module, B_module.

B_module has a style:

```
<style name="my_style”> 
 <item 
  name="@android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/anim_toast_show</item> 
 <item 
 name="@android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/anim_toast_hide</item>
</style>
```

If B_module compile(':A_module')
Build or Clean, report a error location in A_module->Res->values->styles:

> Error:(94, 5) style attribute '@android:attr/windowExitAnimation' not found
>      Error:(94, 5) style attribute '@android:attr/windowEnterAnimation' not found

Solution:
Removing the "@" at the start of the item name.

```
<item name="@android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/anim_toast_show</item>
<item name="@android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/anim_toast_hide</item>
```

to:

```
<item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/anim_toast_show</item>
<item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/anim_toast_hide</item>
```

Comment: I hadn't multiple modules, but I hadn't noticed the @, removing it worked. thanks

Comment: but  if I can not modify the module_B,for example,it comes from third party aar or something,I also get the same error too,how can I handle this problem?

Comment: removing @ from android namespace dos not help @Martinzhangyu

Comment: yes solve my issues after updating gradle version i got this issues

Comment: @lightman1988 have you get any solution even i am getting problem in thirdparty lib

Comment: i am getting error after update android studio and plugin

Comment: somehow fix the issue.

Comment: @VishalThakkar Define the same style in your project  so it  will override the third party values

Comment: @VishalThakkar Even am facing problem with some other third party lib. Can you explain briefly how did you solve this.

Answer (score 5):

Setting `android.enableAapt2=false` in the `gradle.properties` file fixes this issue. See the Stack Overflow question I linked.

It will help you!

Comment: What link do you mean?

Comment: 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated as of end of 2018

Answer (score 3):

**Removing a custom attribute**

I got a similar error when I deleted an attribute for a custom view. The reason the error came up was that I still had xml references to it in my project.

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to search the entire project for the offending attribute and then removing all references to it solved the problem.